# Matrix Inverse in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, math, matrix, datagridview

I'm writing a program to do the Newton Raphson Method for n variable (System of equation) using Datagridview. My problem is to determine the inverse for Jacobian Matrix. I've search in internet to find a solution but a real couldn't get it until now so if someone can help me I will real appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember that if you are trying to calculate `x = inverse(A) . y`, you can equivalently solve the linear system `y = A . x`. It might be easier to find, or to write, code to solve the system of linear equations instead of computing the inverse.

Comment: Does [Linear Equation Systems](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/LinearEquations.html) from Math.NET Numerics help?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've never used Math.NET numeris. However, seems that will help. So thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a recommendation of a library, that is explicitly off topic in Stack Overflow. However below I mention some algorithms that are commonly used; this may help you to find, or write, what you need. I would, though, not recommend writing something, unless you really want to, as it can be tricky to get these algorithms right. If you do decide to write something I'd recommend the QR method, as the easiest to write, though the theory is a little subtle.

First off do you really need to compute the inverse? If, for example, what you need to do is to compute

```
x = inv(J)*y
```

then it's faster and more accurate to treat this problem as

```
solve J*x = y for x
```

The methods below all factor J into other matrices, for which this solution can be done. A good package that implements the factorisation will also have the code to perform the solution.

If you do really really need the inverse often the best way is to solve, one column at a time

```
J*K = I for K, where I is the identity matrix
```

**LU decomposition**

This may well be the fastest of the algorithms described here but is also the least accurate. An important point is that the algorithm must include (partial) pivoting, or it will not work on all invertible matrices, for example it will fail on a rotation through 90 degrees.
What you get is a factorisation of J into:

```
J = P*L*U
where P is a permutation matrix, 
L lower triangular, 
U upper triangular
```

So having factorised, to solve for x we do three steps, each straightforward, and each can be done in place (ie all the x's can be the same variable)

```
Solve P*x1 = y for x1
Solve L*x2 = x1 for x2
Solve U*x = x2 for x
```

**QR decomposition**

This may be somewhat slower than LU but is more accurate. Conceptually this factorises J into

```
J = Q*R
```

Where Q is orthogonal and R upper triangular. However as it is usually implemented you in fact pass y as well as J to the routine, and it returns R (in J) and Q'*y (in the passed y), so to solve for x you just need to solve

```
R*x = y
```

which, given that R is upper triangular, is easy.

**SVD (Singular value decomposition)**

This is the most accurate, but also the slowest. Moreover unlike the others you can make progress even if J is singular (you can compute the 'generalised inverse' applied to y).

I recommend reading up on this, but advise against implementing it yourself.

Briefly you factorise J as

```
J = U*S*V'
```

where U and V are orthogonal and S diagonal.

There are, of course, many other ways of solving this problem. For example if your matrices are very large (dimension in the thousands) an it may, particularly if they are sparse (lots of zeroes), be faster to use an iterative method.

Comment: Real thanks for your clarification dmuir. Now instead to calculate the Inverse matrix I find out that I can easily use other methods which are real good. One of those is the Gauss Elimination whit Pivoting. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).